# Did the US embassy in Kyiv resist hanging Trump's picture while Yovanovitch was ambassador?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, ukraine, embassy, state-department

Trump charges that was the case. As the BBC [reported](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-50520652) yesterday:

> President Donald Trump has pilloried an envoy who testified in the impeachment inquiry, claiming she refused to hang his photo in the US embassy in Ukraine.
>
> Mr Trump told Fox News' morning show former ambassador Marie Yovanovitch "didn't want to hang my picture in the embassy" in Kyiv. [...]
>
> "This ambassador, who everybody says was so wonderful," Mr Trump said, "she wouldn't hang my picture in the embassy.
>
> "She's in charge of the embassy, it took, like, a year and a half, two years." [...]
>
> "The standard is you put the president of the United States' picture in the embassy," he continued. "This was not an angel, this woman, OK?"

But I'm not seeing any reaction from those accused (the former ambassador or embassy staff) or any other attempt to confirm or disprove this claim in that BBC article. So, to what extent is it true what Trump charged?

Comment: I feel so sorry for Trump. All he wanted was to be hung...

Comment: @CGCampbell: because it doesn't make any difference if I do that or not?

Comment: @CGCampbell: come to think of it now, since I asked this question there was a lot more "water under the bridge" in terms of impeachment proceedings etc. It's possible that some relevant details may have been said in those... but with my rather short attention span, I didn't come back to this question to fill in any other details. But maybe someone else would care/like to do so at one point. Marking the question "not interested in any other answers" seems a bit premature (and I generally find it somewhat disconsiderate to accept one own's answers, except in super-clear-cut cases).

Answer (score 37):

NBC has [this rebuttal](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/trump-impeachment-inquiry/live-blog/trump-impeachment-inquiry-live-updates-latest-news-n1065706/ncrd1089626#liveBlogHeader) from Yovanovitch's lawyers:

> Yovanovitch's lawyers rate Trump's embassy portrait claim Pinocchio worthy
>
> Lawyers for former Ambassador to Ukraine Marie Yovanovitch say President Donald Trump’s claim that she refused to hang his picture in the U.S. embassy in Ukraine is false.
>
> “The Embassy in Kyiv hung the official photographs of the president, vice president, and secretary of state as soon as they arrived from Washington, D.C.,” a person connected to her legal team said.

And interestingly, for more context the NBC adds:

> The Washington Post reported in 2017 that pictures of Trump and Vice President Mike Pence still were not being displayed on thousands of federal buildings nearly eight months into Trump's term because the Government Publishing Office had yet to receive the images from the White House. The White House, in turn, said Trump and Pence hadn't decided when to sit for the portraits.

[According to ABC](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/trump-continues-attack-marie-yovanovich-angel/story?id=67228142) that also affected embassies, but it doesn't say which:

> ABC News confirmed with State Department officials that the federal government did not send official portraits out to federal offices and embassies until many months after Trump went into office. It was already 2018 when the pictures of Trump, Vice President Mike Pence and former Secretary of State Rex Tillerson were hung, according to State Department officials.
>
> Lewis Lukens, the former top U.S. diplomat in the United Kingdom, wrote on Twitter that it took the White House almost 15 months to send out official photos.